# Prestashop custom link depending on product manufacturer

Tags: prestashop

I want to make a button with a modal effect on product page with ex. size table. I want to show only this size table depending on acutal product manufacturer.

Ex. Nike shoes

On product page (product.tpl file) button named like "size table". After use the button the modal popup box will show only the Nike shoe size table.

Maybe something like this should work?

```
{if $manufacutrer_name !='Nike'}

    <a href="domain.name/nike-size-table.html" class="button modal">Size table</a>

{/if}
```

Comment: Welcome! Usually we try to avoid thank taglines in the questions to keep them tidier, you can read why in here: "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the manufacturer id, you can do:

```
{if $product->id_manufacturer == 23}
    <a href="domain.name/nike-size-table.html" class="button modal">Size table</a>
{/if}
```